# Issues with High-Resolution WMS Raster Export in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, export

I'm trying to export a raster from a WMS in QGIS. When I specify a resolution below 1 (e.g., 0.1) for both horizontal and vertical dimensions, I notice that a significant portion of the raster gets cut off. Does anyone know why this might be happening or how to address it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A WMS is a picture of the data not the data. There may be restrictions on the size of the map or the amount of time that can be used to draw the map

Comment: make a direct request to the WMS server, rather than export an image retrieved